# Where to find data on different crops

Tags: botany, agriculture

Hello I'm not sure if this is the proper place for this question. If not, I am happy to move it.

I'm trying to find a source of data on different crops, is there some governmental database that houses this kind of data? After looking for a couple hours on google and reading a few different articles, I have not really found what I was looking for.

For example, consider the crops maize, wheat, sorghum and sugarcane. I could be looking at the different kinds of carbohydrates an their proportions in these crops, or I could be wanting to know the amount of water needed to produce some yield, what kind of soil each crop likes as well as how different hybrids and mutants have different needs or qualities.

Comment: Did you try a google search? I got these results, hope they are useful:

http://www.fao.org/land-water/databases-and-software/crop-information/en/

https://world-crops.com/home/

http://www.ecpgr.cgiar.org/resources/germplasm-databases/eccdb-list/